# neo4j: java: can we force GraphDB NOT TO HAVE nodes with duplicate Node_Key? If yes how can we do it?

Tags: java, neo4j, unique-constraint, graph-databases

A sample code and situation related to this is discussed in following question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406867/neo4j-java-error-in-indexhits-getsingle-due-to-multiple-nodes-returned-for-g/15408058#15408058

I'm creating a network graph using neo4j in java.
My requirement is to have nodes with one of it's property `Node_Key` which should be unique, i.e. another node with the same property value should not exist in the graph.

How can we achieve this?

Can we force GraphDB NOT TO HAVE nodes with duplicate Node_Key (or any property with unique value for each node)?

Comment: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/transactions-unique-nodes.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021636/unique-value-in-neo4j-nodes