# How to create unique node in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I'd like to ensure I do not create multiple nodes with my neo4j database.  I see [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-java-embedded-unique-nodes.html#tutorials-java-embedded-unique-get-or-create) that this is the preferred method (even after reviewing this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021636/unique-value-in-neo4j-nodes)), but I do not understand what the code is really doing in that example.  Can someone possibly elaborate for the layman/noob?

Literal code is:

> Create a Cypher execution engine and a unique constraint.

```
try ( Transaction tx = graphdb.beginTx() )
{
    graphdb.schema()
            .constraintFor( DynamicLabel.label( "User" ) )
            .assertPropertyIsUnique( "name" )
            .create();
    tx.success();
}

return new ExecutionEngine( graphdb() );
```

> Use MERGE to create a unique node.

```
Node result = null;
ResourceIterator<Node> resultIterator = null;
try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() )
{
    String queryString = "MERGE (n:User {name: {name}}) RETURN n";
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put( "name", username );
    resultIterator = engine.execute( queryString, parameters ).columnAs( "n" );
    result = resultIterator.next();
    tx.success();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What part of the code are you not sure of? Is it the Cypher or is it the Java? I can explain both, just let me know what exactly you are lacking clarity on. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, kinda both...  I see they (appear) to be creating a constraint with Cypher where the user and name must be unique, correct?  If so, why are they storing things in a hash?  If the insertion to the hash fails (not unique), then the try fails?  If that is so, why even buid the constraint?

Comment: Also, if I have a HUGE collection, does this mean I must create a has of the ENTIRE collection just to see if something is unique?  That would cause a problem if I had, say, a couple million records, right?

Comment: Let me know if the answer I provided answers your second question, if not I'll update it.

Comment: Think I got it now, thanks!  On the command line and not via the API, I suppose if I created the constraint that is listed below (Cypher code) and then submitted a merge statement as well (Cypher again) I could ensure manual entries are unique as well, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The code appears to be creating a constraint with Cypher where the
>   user and name must be unique, correct?

The code to create the constraint in this example is managed in the Java API for Neo4j. Labels group nodes together, and any node can have multiple labels. Refer here to learn more about labels:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/graphdb-neo4j-labels.html

In this case, `User` is a label that is assigned to a set of nodes within the graph. When we create a unique constraint, we tell Neo4j to assert a uniqueness constraint on a property within an arbitrary label.

That's managed in this statement:

```
graphdb.schema()
        .constraintFor( DynamicLabel.label( "User" ) )
        .assertPropertyIsUnique( "name" )
        .create();
tx.success();
```

To do this in Cypher, it looks like this:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (user:User) ASSERT user.name IS UNIQUE
```

Refer here to learn more about Neo4j 2.0's optional schema:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-constraints.html

> If so, why are they storing things in a hash?

In the second chunk of code, which I've copied here for easy reference:

```
Node result = null;
ResourceIterator<Node> resultIterator = null;
try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() )
{
    String queryString = "MERGE (n:User {name: {name}}) RETURN n";
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put( "name", username );
    resultIterator = engine.execute( queryString, parameters ).columnAs( "n" );
    result = resultIterator.next();
    tx.success();
    return result;
}
```

We are wrapping a managed call within a transactional context. On the 4th line, we are creating our query string which is: `MERGE (n:User {name: {name}}) RETURN n`, which means we want to `MATCH` or `CREATE` a user with an arbitrary name. The name is provided as the parameter `{name}` which is supplied within the hash map named `parameters` on the following line. The hash map is acting as a simple key/value list for our parameters where the key must match the provided parameter in the Cypher query, in this case `{name}`.

```
resultIterator = engine.execute( queryString, parameters ).columnAs( "n" );
```

The transaction is then executed by supplying the query string, containing the Cypher statement with a declared parameter placeholder, and also the parameter map containing the key/value list.

> If the insertion to the hash fails (not unique), then the try fails? If that is so, why even buid the constraint?

Since the `MERGE` clause gets or creates (create happens if the record does not exist), a uniqueness constraint cannot be triggered within this context. If you were to try to use the `CREATE` statement to create a node with a duplicate `name` property, then the transaction would fail. The same is true if you attempted to `SET` a name property on another node with a duplicate `name` property within the set of nodes with the `User` label.